# Mock any objects of a class

Tags: java, mocking

How can I mock any objects of a class.

What I want is for any file object to return `true` when `exists()` is called on it.

Something like:

```
Mockito.mock(File.class)
//return true for any object of File that calls exist()
File file = new File("thisDoesntExist");
assertEquals(true, file.exists());
```

How can this be done?

This is the method under test (cut down)

```
@Override
public void load(InputArchive archive, int idx)
{
    archive.beginNode("Files", idx);

    File file = new File(archive.load("Path"));
    if(file.exists())
    {
         //if it gets here it'll pass the test
    }
}
```

I think that the above will solve my problem, but in case there's a better/alternative way to solve my problem I'll tell you why I'm trying to do this:

The reason I want to do this is that I'm reading an XML which will create a file based off a  tag, it will then test this fileObjectCreatedFromXML to see if it exists and if it does then it will do some other stuff which I need it to do.

Comment: Can you inject the file anywhere; i.e. can you pass it in as a parameter?  That'd make this sort of thing easier.

Comment: @Makoto no, the file is created from the XML, I can however change the contents of the XML, does that make it easier?

Comment: Could you share the method under test? It's rather hard to give suggestions with so little information. However, unless you can change the file-creating code so that you could e.g. inject a factory that would be used for creating the file (and could be mocked in your test to return a `File` that always returns `true` from `exists`), there is not much that can be done.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I've added the method

Comment: @MickMnemonic are you saying that instead of the File file = ... I make it File file = loadFile(), and then just mock the return of that loadFile method to return my mocked file object?

Comment: Yes, something like that. In general, it's impossible to mock something you create with `new` inside the method under test -- you have to provide some way to inject the mock into the method. One way would be to have your class under test to use a small helper class (e.g. `FileFactory`), which you can constructor-inject, for creating the files.

Comment: @MickMnemonic That's unfortunate if that's the only way because I'd also like to test that the path was correct which I can't do if I do that. I'll need another test. Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you actually want to test here? As the `load` method in the class under test has a `void` return type, all you really can test are possible side effects of the method. If you want to test that `InputArchive.load()` loads from the correct path, you should definitely have a separate test for that class.

Answer (score 2):

Is possible to mock your `File` object even if is created inside your class and you do not have any way to inject it or reference it. 
I had this problem few weeks ago and `PowerMock` can help you here.

You have to annotate your test class to run with `PowerMockRunner`. See the following example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClassThatWillBeTested.class)
public class MyUnitTest{
    private File mockedFile = mock(File.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedFile);
    }
}

@Test
public void myTestMethod(){
    //test your method here...
}
```

If you create only one file object this should work well for you.
Also now you can manipulate your mock object to return what you want.

```
when(mockedFile.exists()).thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: +1 because it answers the question, but unfortunately doesn't help me as I can't use powermock as using it causes tests to run too slow

Comment: Isn't it possible to use powermock only for the current class? The impact for one unit test class shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: yeh but if it's used in one testClass then other people will start using it too, and then soon you end up with it being used heavily and the unit tests start taking minutes to run.

Comment: Never heard/encountered situations like this until now. Anyway, you can try with reflection, or better, declare the field as a class member with package visibility so you can play with it in unit tests. Also see @VisibleForTesting annotation. From my experience sometimes is better to lessen the visibility a little but just for testing purposes.

Comment: PS: if answers the question I would rather mark it as checked/solved(since this is the purpose of Stackoverflow), maybe some other people need this answer and is easy for them to spot it. Regarding your use-case you could post a new question on which you could mention the performance issue fact.

Comment: That's what upvotes are for, accepting is if it helped me.